# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'chart1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, multithreading, charts, delegates, invoke

I am trying to update my chart in some cases. I call the `Plot` methot with in another method. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the) solution but it is for textBox so I can't implement it to my code. I searched on the internet but I couldn't find a solution for charts.

How can I solve this problem for adding points to a chart?

```
private void Plot()
    {
            chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY
                            (plotValues[0,1], plotValues[0,0]);
            chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY
                           (plotValues[1, 1], plotValues[1, 0]);

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the answer in your link?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY
                        (plotValues[0,1], plotValues[0,0]));
```

(or InvokeAsync in case you want to run is async / don't need to wait for the operation to be finished on your other thread)